# Unbiased estimation of regression coefficients conditional on a range of the dependent variable

Tags: regression, bias, conditional-expectation, censoring, tobit-regression

I am interested in the relationship between a set of explanatory variables and a particular outcome variable for values of the outcome above a certain cutoff. Can I simply regress the outcome on the explanatory variables, or do I need a two-stage procedure like the Tobit model for unbiased results?

Note that I am **not** trying to estimate the relationship for the entire population. I know I'd need correction in that case. But here I want unbiased results of the relationship *conditional* on an outcome in the top few percentiles of the range of outcome values.